# Different versions of the same program installed. How do I give precedence to a specific version?

Tags: bash, unix, path, cabal, apt-get

On Ubuntu, I have installed Pandoc using first `apt-get` and then using the haskell cabal package manager. How can I make the `pandoc` terminal command refer to the newer pandoc? I have added the cabal bin path to the system path in the my ~/.bashrc script like so:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
export PATH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create an alias to the new binary in /etc/profile (general) or ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc (just one user).

```
 alias pandoc="/path/of/new/pandoc"
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, I see. To make a terminal command have precedence over another, I just need to make sure that it appears first in the path, like so:

```
PATH=~/.cabal/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```